# AWS OpenSearch 1.3 - change index analyzer in existing index

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, opensearch

I have an existing index that was created from snapshot from another OS cluster. In its index settings it refers to a package that exists in another OS cluster, which I also installed in new OS. Unfortunately, package ID is generated by AWS and it needs to be changed in newly created index from an old one. What is the best way to go about updating it in existing index?

```
"settings": {
    "index": {
        "refresh_interval": "1s",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "provided_name": "FOO",
        "creation_date": "123",
        "analysis": {
            "analyzer": {
                "lc_stop_multi_stem": {
                    "filter": [
                        "snowball"
                    ],
                    "type": "stop",
                    "stopwords_path": "analyzers/F999"
                }
            }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "58585",
        "version": {
            "created": "123"
        }
    }
}
```

TLDR, old path/package - analyzers/F999 need to be changed to new path/package - analyzers/F777 in existing index.